# skip row item if value empty using for loop php

Tags: php

I print some data using for loop.My code work corrcetly but I want to skip  row  if specific value  will be empty

my code

```
$count = count($cd);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{

print'["'.$cd[$i][2].'", '.$cd[$i][4].', '.$cd[$i][5].','.$count.',"'.$cd[$i][8].'","'.$cd[$i][0].'", "'.strip_tags($cd[$i][3]).'","'.$cd[$i][6].'"]';

if ($i < ($count - 1))
 {
    echo ', ';
 }
}
```

If value of `$cd[$i][2] and $cd[$i][4]` will be blank the print skip this row

any idea

Answer (score 2):

Skip the empty rows with by using `if` condition and check if not empty then print.

```
$count = count($cd);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
   if(!empty($cd[$i][2]) && !empty($cd[$i][4]))
     print'["'.$cd[$i][2].'", '.$cd[$i][4].', '.$cd[$i][5].','.$count.',"'.$cd[$i][8].'","'.$cd[$i][0].'", "'.strip_tags($cd[$i][3]).'","'.$cd[$i][6].'"]';

   if ($i < ($count - 1))
   {
       echo ', ';
   }
}
```

Comment: I think we should address the fact that OP is concatenating a string to make an array pattern, when instead, it should just be pushed onto the array stack.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to check if something is "blank":

1. **`if(empty($var))`** - `empty($var)` is `true` if the variable is *not set*, or it has an *empty value* (empty = *empty string* OR *zero* OR *null* OR *false*)
2. **`if(!strlen($var))`** - this is almost the same, except if variable is not set, you will get a warning, and *zero* is not empty value, obviousely in this case (as it checks length of the value).
3. **`if(!isset($var))`** - `isset($var)` is `true` if the variable is set, and `false` otherwise. So, `!isset($var)` is the exact opposite, because of negation.

So, depending on your definition of **blank**, You might need to check different things here.
But in general, the condition would look like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
   if(empty($cd[$i][2]) && empty($cd[$i][4])) continue; // skip this line entirely

   ... // the rest of your code in the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$count = count($cd);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{
if(!empty($cd[$i][2]) && !empty( $cd[$i][4])) {

print'["'.$cd[$i][2].'", '.$cd[$i][4].', '.$cd[$i][5].','.$count.',"'.$cd[$i][8].'","'.$cd[$i][0].'", "'.strip_tags($cd[$i][3]).'","'.$cd[$i][6].'"]';


if ($i < ($count - 1))
 {
    echo ', ';
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a little bit of a different approach from everyone else... (using foreach instead)

Take this for example:

```
$count = count($cd);
$i = 0;
$sep = ',';

foreach($cd as $item){
  if ($i == ($count - 1)){$sep = '';}

  if(!empty($item[2]) && !empty($item[4])){
    echo '["' . $item[2] . '", ' . $item[4] . ', ' . $item[5] . ',' . $count . ',"' . $item[8] . '","' . $item[0] . '", "' . strip_tags($item[3]) . '","' . $item[6] . '"]' . $sep;
  }else{
    $count --;
  }

  $i++;
}
```

Not too sure about whether it will be slower but I've always preferred a `foreach` statement to a `for` statement.

All criticisms welcome